# React Redux Router not routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, router

I have the following code:

```js
/* index.js */

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { Router, Route, Link } from 'react-router'

import App from './components/app';
import DetailComponent from './components/detailcomponent';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App} />
        <Route path="/detail" component={DetailComponent} />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  , document.querySelector('.container'));



/* components/app.js */

import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

import UserListing from '../containers/user-listing';
import UserDetail from '../containers/user-detail';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <UserListing />
        <UserDetail />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


/* components/detailcomponent.js */

import React from 'react';
import { Component } from 'react';

export default class DetailComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        This is the Detail Component!
      </div>
    );
  }
}



/* containers/user-detail.js */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class UserDetail extends Component {
  render() {
    if (!this.props.user) {
      return <div>Select a user to view details.</div>;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Details for:</h3>
        <div>Username: {this.props.user.username}</div>
        <div>E-mail: {this.props.user.email}</div>
        <div>Twitter: {this.props.user.twitter}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    user: state.activeUser
  };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(UserDetail);


/* containers/user-listing.js */

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { chosenUser } from '../actions/index';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';

class UserListing extends Component {
  renderList() {
    return this.props.users.map((user) => {
      return (
        <li
          key={user.username}
          onClick={() => this.props.chosenUser(user)}
          className="list-group-item">
          {user.username}, {user.email}, {user.twitter}
        </li>
      );
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul className="list-group col-sm-4">
        {this.renderList()}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    users: state.users
  };
}


function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators({ chosenUser }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(UserListing);



/* reducers/index.js */

import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import UserReducer from './reducer_user';
import ActiveUser from './reducer_active_user';

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  users: UserReducer,
  activeUser: ActiveUser
});

export default rootReducer;


/* reducers/reducer_active_user.js */

export default function(state = null, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
  case 'USER_SELECTED':
    return action.payload;
  }
  return state;
}

  
/* reducers/reducer_user.js */
  
export default function () {
  return [
    {username: 'John Doe', email: 'john@doe.com', twitter: 'johndoe1'},
    {username: 'Paul Smith', email: 'smith.paul@csswizardry.com', twitter: 'csswizardry'},
    {username: 'Petra Tweets', email: 'petra@tweets.me.com', twitter: 'petra'},
    {username: 'Mark Chills', email: 'chillmark@company.com', twitter: 'chillymark12'},
    {username: 'John McIntyre', email: 'comic@mcintyre.com', twitter: 'jokesforfun'},
  ];
}
```

I would like to create a route '/detail' where I'd like to display essentially what's now in containers/user-detail.js.

Now when I change the URL to /detail, the App component get's displayed.

Could you advise on how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your route configuration appears to be correct, so my guess is that your code is not recompiling. This could be due to, for example, a syntax error in your JS.

I'd recommend deleting your compiled JS, then seeing if you can rebuild, using your build tool (Webpack, Browserify, etc.), watching the console for errors.

> Note: It's hard to reproduce the problem because your snippet isn't runnable. You could use this as your starting point: jsfiddle.net / reactjs/69z2wepo/